# Intellij EL expression validation issue in Javascript

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, el

How to correct use JSF variables in javascript? 
My version works how I expected, but IDEA shows error:

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you run the application?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, it work fine.

Comment: So the problem is not 'inject variable in javascript' but 'intelliji wrongfully showing an error when using EL in javascript'. Good titles are important

Comment: @Kukeltje i don`t know, who edit my question. Initially titles was other. Besides I do not know if my method is correct

Comment: Same problem in IntelliJ 2018.3

Comment: It is additionally annoying, because IDEA does not recognize the usage, so e.g. it might recommend you to delete unused productView.product.relations...

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF should evaluate your EL expression the same way that in the rest of the XHTML file. The only thing you should take care about is that JSF evaluates the EL expressions in server side, and the JS code is executed in client side (keep those cycles in mind and under control).

On the other side, the error you're getting seems to be Intellij complaining about an unrecognized expression in the javascript code. You could configure the IDE to skip that kind of markers.